# Google Sheets returns wrong results

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

Google Sheets gives me the wrong result. In the first row (`M38`) I write the number manually; in the second row (`M39`) I have a `SUM` for my data. Both results are the same, as you see. However, when I apply the formula  `IF(M38 = M39, true, false)` the result is `FALSE`.

Could someone explain to me the reason or what is wrong?

[image] [image]

Comment: *both results are same as you see* Recommended reading: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: pls, share a copy of your sheet

Comment: Welcome. Cell display values could be different from the actual values. Please add more details. If you decide to share a demo spreadsheet, please add to it only the minimum sheets, formulas, values, etc. to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

- **reason 1:** the 1st cell is not formatted properly (eg. it's formatted as text). try to check it with **`=ISNUMBER(M38)`** - if it returns **`TRUE`** this reason is invalid
- **reason 2:** cell **M39** shows you only the rounded number, not the whole number. (it could be for example: **`957.9787000000666667`** and you see only first 10 characters **`957.9787000`**). you can wrap your formula in **M39** into **`=ROUND(M39_formula_here,7)`** or try to check it with: **`=IF(M38 = ROUND(M39,7), TRUE, FALSE)`**
- **reason 3:** it's also possible that **M39** is returned as a text-formatted string. in that case wrap your **M39** formula into **`VALUE`** - **`=VALUE(M39_formula_here)`**